# How to minimize resolutions of flutter web?

Tags: html, flutter

I have made a website in flutter web
Now I want to minimize its design like we do in browser. I want to do it in material app or something so that resolutions of website will become smaller.

This is how my website looks like in 100% screen size currently:

[image]

What I want is it to look like in 100 is this:

[image]

I want my website to minimize to 75 or 80%.

I have tried `Transform.scale` and`FractionalSizedBox` widgets but they are just covering 75% of screen
I want my website to cover 100% of screen but with smaller resolutions